# How to edit a Custom Field in Jira v.5.0?

Tags: jira, edit, custom-fields

I try to edit one of my custom fields. Like in this [instruction](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+a+Custom+Field#ConfiguringaCustomField-edit). But i have not screen "Viewing Custom Fields". Why? Any idea?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you logged in as an Administrator? If so, you should be able to select Administration in the upper right-hand corner and then click the 'Issues' tab and choose 'Fields'.  This should take you to a list of all of your custom fields.

Comment: Yes, I logged as an Administrator. I click 'Issues' but in 'Fields' i see only 'Custom Fields' 'Field Configurations' and 'Field Configuration Schemes'. 'Viewing Custom Fields" aren't present. And also anywhere there is no button 'Edit' like in instruction.

Comment: The documentation seems to be from an older version of Jira. You should be able to edit from the 'Custom Fields' tab.